# How to perform addtion list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting the following error when I try to perform this operation:

```
prob1 += sum([x[d][s]*Dic_Trancosts[d][s] for (d,s) in routes]) #add the DC cost
**TypeError**: string indices must be integers
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

```
dcCap=[30, 30, 40, 70]
dcCost=[700, 800, 1600, 800]
customerDemand=[40, 30, 40]
transcostlist_of_lists=[[4, 16, 8, 4], 
[6, 6, 6, 9], 
[12, 15, 7, 8]]
DClist=['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
Demandlist=['D1', 'D2', 'D3'] 
import pulp
from pulp import *
# The supply capacity data is made into a dictionary
Dic_DCCapacity = makeDict([DClist], dcCap,0) #default 0 if no data entry is 
found
Dic_DCCapacity
# The fixed cost of each DC is made into a dictionary
Dic_DCCost = makeDict([DClist], dcCost,0)
Dic_DCCost
# The demand data is made into a dictionary
Dic_Demand = makeDict([Demandlist], customerDemand,0)
Dic_Demand
# The cost data is made into a dictionary
Dic_Trancosts = makeDict([Demandlist,DClist], transcostlist_of_lists,0)
Dic_Trancosts

prob1 = LpProblem("Network Design Problem1", LpMinimize)
#Each pair of (Demandlist,DClist) is associated with a decision variable, 
#indicating the flow between DC and customer

#Decision variable (binary) that is associated with whether or not to open a DC  

routes = [(d,s) for d in Demandlist for s in DClist]
routes

prob1 += sum([x[d][s]*Dic_Trancosts[d][s] for (d,s) in routes]) \
#add the DC cost


# Supply maximum constraints are added to prob for each supply node (DC)

for s in DClist:
prob1 += sum([x[d][s] for d in Demandlist]) <= Dic_DCCapacity[s]

# Demand minimum constraints are added to prob for each demand node (bar)

# Write out the lp file to you directory
```

Comment: is there an error message? which result is expected?

Comment: Also, the example will be much easier to understand if you reduce it. Please read the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `x` is not defined anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit hard to tell without example but this error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

generaly means that you are trying to index a string with something other than intiger:

```
>>> s = "my string"
>>> s[1]
'y'
>>> s["y"]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    s["y"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

My best guess is that `x` is a string not a dictionary and when you try to index it with `x[d][s]` where `d` and `s` are strings Python throws an error.

Not sure what `x` is suppose to be in your code but I would start looking there